# Integer Exclusion Invalid Qualifier Question

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to prevent execution of a sub list when my defined variable (SlideIndex) is 0 or blank. However, I'm receiving an "Invalid Qualifier" error on the `If SlideIndex.Value <> "0" And SlideIndex.Value <> "" Then` and am unsure as to why. When I debug.print SlideIndex, the value shown in the Immediate window is 0 so I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ReplaceTable()
  Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim i As Object
  
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim SlideIndex As Integer
  Dim myslide As Object
  Dim SlideShape
  Dim ShapeContent As Range
  Dim Title As Variant
  Dim TitleList As Variant
  
  'Compiles list of Titles from sheet1 
  TitleList  = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2:D20").Value
  
  'Runs through each slide # defined on sheet1
  For Each Title In TitleList
  
    'Looks up title and associated slide index on sheet1
    SlideIndex = Application.VLookup(title, Sheet1.Range("D2:H50"), 5, False)
    'change title value on template tab based on i=slide#
    Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Value = title
    Debug.Print SlideIndex
    'Skip if Slide # on sheet1 is 0 or blank - indicating exclusion
    If SlideIndex.Value <> "0" And SlideIndex.Value <> "" Then
        'Prepares tabular excel data for extraction
        Call DuplicateSheet
        Call CopyRange
        Call DeleteRows
        Call reshade
        Call ReplaceRange
        Set ShapeContent = Worksheets(1).Range("D6:V24")
        ShapeContent.Copy
        myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Select 'sets view to currently constructed slide
        myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes(2).Delete 'main table is index 2
        myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
        Set myslide = myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex)
        Set myShape = myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)
            myShape.Left = 18
            myShape.Top = 170
        Call DeleteSheets
    Else
    End If
  Next
  
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Slideindex is an integer, it does not have a value property.  Just use "If SlideIndex = ......'

Comment: "If SlideIndex =       "  results in an Expected:expression error. Please advise

Comment: "If SlideIndex = 0 then" seems to work.

Comment: The ..... was a placeholder for wahtever came next. You would probably benefit from working through a tutorial for VBA.  I'd also recommend that you install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the code inspections.